# Zero bytes in file

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, xor

I am writing a simple script encrypting files with **XOR**, and I noticed that if there are zero bytes in a file block, the key is present in the encrypted block in plaintext.

For me this is unacceptable, so I encoded the open block of the file in **base64**, then the key is no longer public, however, I can't get away from the idea that there are a lot of null bytes in the file, and by statistical analysis it might be possible to decrypt it.

So the question is, is there a solution to this problem? (e.g. replacing zero bytes with one of the key bytes), and an off-topic question that concerns me, am I right to understand that algorithms like **AES** do not use **XOR** as an encryption algorithm, or somehow solve the problem of zero bytes in a file?

Comment: You should learn basic of encryption implementations: you just found one of the many problems. Usually we requires a block size, and we fill data with random numbers. (Note: you have the same problem also if your message length is not multiple of key. And consider if one can guess some part of message, she can get quickly the original key. (XOR is not much secure). But again: there are many implementation tricks: do not do new encryption libraries (to be used for security) if you do not have good understanding of problems (not just theory, but history of bugs and security problems)

Comment: I really feel a gap in my knowledge that urgently needs to be filled, would you mind telling me the name of this problem so I can look into it, my attempts to find the problem on google have gotten me nowhere:(

usually we need a block size and we fill it with random numbers, could you explain why we fill the block with random numbers ? what does it do and how does it solve the key disclosure problem

Comment: What you are trying to implement is a simple stream cipher, which is very insecure - as you have discovered, with a known plaintext attack - it doesn't have to be zeroes, just anything, it's then trivial to extract the key if it's a short key that is cyclically repeated. What one normally do is feed the key into an algorithm that then generate a stream of bytes that are randomly distributed and computationally infeasible to predict. If you instead just generate a really random key as long as the plain text that is never reused, it's a perfect cipher, aka a one time pad. Google stream cipher.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, is there a solution to this problem?

Sure, it is called [IV (initialization vector)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector). Random (or unique) data passed with the ciphertext to prevent reusing the same cipherstream.

It is very unsafe to reuse the same cipherstream (in case of the stream modes, like XOR). IV basically is creating different cipherstream for each encryption even with the same key.

> am I right to understand that algorithms like AES do not use XOR as an encryption algorithm

The stream [encryption modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes) (like CTR, GCM) are using XOR, that's why reusing (or not using) IV has catastrophic consequences.